# Windows 10 preview PC getting served static and DHCP address

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip, windows-10-preview

**Setup**

- PC: Latest Windows Tech Preview
- IP address set to static.
- Router: R7000/DDWRT

**L**ately I've notice, when checking devices that are connected to my router, that this PC has been showing the static address which it's always been assigned (192.168.0.110) and randomly a DHCP address (192.168.0.151). I can only see the DHCP address on my router, ipconfig doesn't show a DHCP address even exsisting. I have tried accessing this PC over the LAN with windows file explorer, using either address, and both work as if they were the same address.

**I**s this most likely a Windows Tech Preview glitch or is there a different reason this could be happening? I've attached a screenshot of my ipconfig. I can't make sense of it.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot does not match the information you provided.  I am slightly confused about what your question is exactly.

Comment: For some reason my router (not pc) shows a static AND DHCP address assigned to this PC. I ONLY have it set to static 192.168.0.110 (as shown in ipconfig). So I am wondering why my router is showing my PC as also having the dhcp 192.168.0.151 address? As you can see my ipconfig doesn't show the 192.168.0.151, but I can connect to this PC via that address. It seems really odd to me, so I was wondering if there could be a reason that DHCP address is happening? I can't find where my PC is getting the address, I just know it has it alongside my static address.

Comment: And obviously if the random DHCP address that works but doesn't show up in ipconfig make no sense to anyone, I will consider it something with the Tech Preview since I've never noticed it on my router until recently.

Answer (score -2):

I've run into the same problem. You need to switch on DHCP in TCP/IP protocol's properties. It's strange, but after update it was switched off by default.

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the proposed question.